# How can I prove exactly half elements of $H$, subgroup of G, are even.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am trying to solve exercise 24 of the book *Contemporary Abstract Algebra* by Gallian.

> Suppose $n$ is an even positive integer and $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_n$. Prove that either every member of $H$ is even or exactly half of the members of $H$ are even.

**My attempt**: Let $H$ is generated by an even number, then $H$ will contain all even members.
**Observation:** The assumption $n$ is even is used in the case when $H$ is generated by $1$.

**Question** : I stuck here, I even don't know that am i going in right direction or not. How can I show that if $H$ is not generated by even number, then $H$ has exactly half even members? 
Need hint please.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since the order $|\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}|$ is equal to $n$, Lagrange's theorem tells us that $|H|$ must divide $n$ for any subgroup $H$. Let $m=|H|$ so that $n=km$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}_+$.

As a subgroup of a cyclic group, $H$ is cyclic and generated by the remainder class $[k]_n$ and then $H=\{ [ak]_n\ |\ a=0, 1, \dots, m-1\}$. Since $n$ is even, at least one of $k, m$ is even. If $k$ is even and of the form $k=2b$, then $H=\{[2ab]_n\ |\ a=0, \dots, m-1\}$ and each element of $H$ is even. If $m$ is even, then we have the elements $[0]_n, [2k]_n, \dots, [(m-2)k]_n$, and there are $\frac{m}{2}$ of them (= half of $H$), and the other half is or isn't even.

Comment: Can we prove the statement without Lagrange's theorem. Because the book has not introduced Lagrange's theorem yet.